How to plot a histogram of a pulse-level quantum circuit simulation in QuTiP?
The qutip_qip package allows for pulse-level quantum circuit simulation, compared to for instance the gate-level quantum circuit simulation found in Qiskit (to understand the difference, scroll to the bottom where you'll find a response generated by ChatGPT).
In Qiskit, it is very straightforward to design a quantum circuit and run a simulation on it. The "shots" argument allows one to define the number of simulation runs. Finally, one can retrieve the count of each possible outcome state and visualise the statistics in a histogram.
I want to achieve this while using the qutip_qip package. For the sake of a simple demonstration, I can create a single-qubit quantum circuit initialised in the zero-state and apply a Hadamard gate (denoted "SNOT" in QuTiP). For the simulation I am interested in the superconducting hardware, so I choose scqubits_processor as processor and run the simulation.
from qutip_qip.operations import Gate
from qutip_qip.circuit import QubitCircuit
from qutip import basis, tensor
from qutip_qip.operations import hadamard_transform
from qutip_qip.device import SCQubits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

num_qubits = 1

qc = QubitCircuit(num_qubits)
qc.add_gate("SNOT", targets=0)

# Define the initial state |0>
scqubits_processor = SCQubits(num_qubits = num_qubits)
scqubits_processor.load_circuit(qc)
initial_state = basis ([3], [0]) # 3 - level

result = scqubits_processor.run_state(initial_state)

If I were now able to run this simulation several times and plot a histogram, I would expect two equally tall bars for the ground state and the first excited state. But I have so far been unable to produce such a visualisation. Does anyone know whether this is possible in my given framework?
(Difference between pulse-level quantum circuit simulation and gate-level quantum circuit simulation: Pulse-level quantum circuit simulation models the detailed control signals (pulses) used to manipulate qubits, capturing the precise dynamics of the quantum hardware, including effects like control imperfections and crosstalk. Gate-level quantum circuit simulation, on the other hand, abstracts these details, representing the circuit as a sequence of idealized logical gates applied to qubits, assuming perfect execution. Pulse-level simulations are more accurate for realistic hardware behavior but computationally intensive. Gate-level simulations are simpler and faster, suitable for higher-level algorithm development. Both approaches are essential, with pulse-level for hardware optimization and gate-level for algorithm design.)
